# Assinatura de uma função genérica em Kotlin

Tags: sintaxe, genéricos, kotlin

Estava vendo a parte de *generics* e gostaria de saber por que se usa o

```
fun <T> addToList(vararg  arg : T): ArrayList<T> {
```

e não o

```
fun addToList(vararg  arg : T): ArrayList<T> {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O motivo exato teria que perguntar para quem criou essa sintaxe. O meu "chute educado" é que seria mais complicado fazer o *parser* de outra forma. Ele poderia considerar que o `T` que aparece no argumento é mesmo um tipo chamado `T` e não uma variável genérica da assinatura e isto seria, no mínimo, ambíguo. Com a indicação inicial, antes de qualquer uso na assinatura, que `T` é um tipo genérico, o seu uso posterior deixa claro que é o *slot* genérico do tipo e não um tipo concreto chamado `T`.